# Files disappear on Laravel storage folder

Tags: laravel, cpanel

I have a laravel application running in a cpanel webhost. My app saves some images in this path "storage/app/custom", and the problem is, files disappear for no reason.

Anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Some external process doing somthing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.